# Managing libraries in Ubuntu/Xubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have been using Xubuntu for about a year, and I can't solve one problem (I know that reinstalling OS will certainly help but still I think I will face this problem many times).
Normally, there are two folders where libraries are located (or I think that there are only two necessary ones so that programs will install and work normally). They are similar to each other in content

```
~/usr/

~/usr/local/
```

The only thing I haven't understood is whether which folder is searched by software first. I had many problems with that. For instance, when I tried to launch Software Center, I have got an error

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 33, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk
```

So, Gtk is originally in gi.repository which was present in the first folder that I have mentioned, but was absent in the second one. When I removed gi.repository from second folder, it gave me second error similar to the first

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for GObject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 31, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject
ImportError: cannot import name GObject
```

GObject was present in the second folder while was absent in the first, and I have deleted it as I mentioned. When I reinstalled it again, it returned to the first error. I solved this problem by direct reinstalling OS, but I think that it will cause more problems in the future.
So how can I manage programs to install, search and use libraries from only one folder? Sorry if this question is long or stupid, I'm a novice in Xubuntu :)